# Finding residues in a complex integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{z^6\,\mathrm{d}z}{(z^4+1)^2}$ using Laurent series expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I am trying to compute
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{z^6\,\mathrm{d}z}{(z^4+1)^2}.$$
I am getting stuck on computing the residues.  I am only considering the residues when $z=\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\mathrm{i}\pi}4}$ and $z=\mathrm{e}^{\frac{3\mathrm{i}\pi}4}$ since we are taking the integral from $0$ to $\infty$. When computing the residues, I am getting a computational nightmare.  For instance,
$$\underset{z=\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\mathrm{i}\pi}4}}{\textrm{Res}}\,f(z)=\lim_{z\rightarrow\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\mathrm{i}\pi}4}}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\frac{z^6}{\left(z-\mathrm{e}^{\frac{3\mathrm{i}\pi}4}\right)^2\left(z-\mathrm{e}^{\frac{5\mathrm{i}\pi}4}\right)^2\left(z-\mathrm{e}^{\frac{7\mathrm{i}\pi}4}\right)^2},$$
and the derivative calculation has been quite messy.

I've also tried using $\frac{1+\mathrm{i}}{\sqrt2}$ in place of $\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\mathrm{i}\pi}4}$, and similar representations for the other roots, in the hopes of the calculation maybe "cleaning up" a bit. I was wondering if anyone could see anything that I am missing that would make computing this derivative nicer, or if these residues are just computationally "ugly".

Thank you!

Comment: I get this.  If $\omega$ is a zero of $z^4+1$, then your residue at $z=\omega$  is $(3/16)\overline{\omega}$

Comment: I suppose my question is about the derivative.  Is there a "shortcut" you are using, or is the traditional method really the only way.  Thank you!

Comment: Expand as a Laurent series in $(z-\omega)$.  You only need the first two terms.

Comment: @GEdgar If you have time, could you elaborate on how to expand in a Laurent Series as an answer? I am just having some issues expanding it, and am not sure if I am making a mistake, or if there is an easier way to go about than with partial fractions.  I would be more than happy to accept that answer and award the bounty!  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's compute the residue by finding a few terms of the Laurent series for
$$
p(z) = \frac{z^6}{(z^4+1)^2}
$$
at $\omega = e^{i\pi/4} = \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$.
To expand in powers of $z-\omega$, I prefer to write $r=z-\omega$ and expand in powers of $r$.

$$
p(r+\omega) = \frac{(r+\omega)^6}{((r+\omega)^4+1)^2}
$$
Do this in small steps.  As $r \to 0$:
$$
N:=(r+\omega)^6 = \omega^6+6\omega^5 r + O(r^2)
= -i - \omega r + O(r^2)
\\
(r+\omega)^4 = \omega^4 + 4 \omega^3 r + 6 \omega^2 r^2 + O(r^3) 
= -1+4i\omega r + 6 i r^2 + O(r^3)
\\
(r+\omega)^4 + 1 = 4i\omega r + 6 i r^2 + O(r^3)
\\
D = \big((r+\omega)^4 + 1\big)^2 = -16i r^2 - 48 \omega r^3 + O(r^4)
\\
p(r+\omega) = \frac{N}{D} =
\frac{-i - \omega r + O(r^2)}{-16i r^2 - 48 \omega r^3 + O(r^4)}
= \frac{1}{16 r^2}\left(\frac{1 - 6 i\omega r+O(r^2)}{1 - 3 i \omega r+O(r^2)}\right)
\\
=\frac{1}{16 r^2} \big(1 - 3 i \omega r + O(r^2)\big)
= \frac{1}{16} r^{-2} - \frac{3 i \omega}{16} r^{-1} + O(1)
$$
So we see that the residue is
$$
\frac{-3i\omega}{16} = \frac{3-3i}{16\sqrt{2}}
$$

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you so much, @GEdgar!  I will award this bounty as soon as enough time passes for it to let me.  Thank you!

Comment: This is a pole of order $2$, so we only need two terms in our final computation to reach the $r^{-1}$ term.  The same method works for higher order poles, but becomes more complicated, because we need to compute more terms.

Comment: why would the goal be to get the $r^{-1}$ term and not the $r^{-2}$ term since it is a pole of order $2$?

Comment: The **residue** is the coefficient of the $r^{-1}$ term.  This should be explained in any complex variables text.

Comment: Oh, yeah, duh, of course.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: I am trying to finish this problem, but I can't seem to get the correct answer.  Wolfram is telling me the integral is $\frac{3\pi}{8\sqrt{2}}$.  I follow your procedure on how to find the reside at $\omega$, and then I'm multiplying it by $\pi i$, but I am not getting the answer... am I missing something silly?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega=e^{i\pi/4}$.

Let $Z_n=z-\omega^n$.

$$f(z):=\frac{z^6}{(Z_3 Z_5 Z_7)^2}$$

$$\ln f=6\ln z -2\ln Z_3-2\ln Z_5-2\ln Z_7$$

$$\frac{f’}{f}=\frac6z-\frac2{Z_3}-\frac2{Z_5}-\frac2{Z_7}$$

$$f’(z)=f(z)\left[\frac6z-\frac2{Z_3}-\frac2{Z_5}-\frac2{Z_7}\right]$$

The residue equals $f’(\omega)$. The rest is just algebra.